# Access javascripts functions from source WKWebView (window.opener)

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, wkwebview, window.opener

In my iOS app, I have 2 `WKWebView` controls to simulate parent/child relationship of 2 tab/window in our web app so that we can reuse all those javascripts. Problem is that there is no generic communication channel between these 2 `WKWebView`s.

**Web Architecture**:
- The first/master window loads our internal javascript functions with links opening in second/child window.
- The second/child window loads third party web content.
- The third party content communicates with our system using javascript form source window (using window.opener / window.parent API bridge).

Now, in the **native app**, this is what I'm doing to reuse existing javascripts and simulate web archtecture -

a. Below js call from the webpage in **1st WKWebView** -

```
  window.open("http://localhost/child.html", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
```

b. The WKUIDelegate intercepts this call (a) and opens **2nd WKWebView** -

```
- (nullable WKWebView *)webView:(WKWebView *)webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration forNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction windowFeatures:(WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures {
    // Here, window.open js calls are handled by loading the request in another/new web view
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    WebViewController *webViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebViewController"];
    webViewController.loadURLString = navigationAction.request.URL.absoluteString;

    // Show controller without interfering the current flow of API call, thus dispatch after a fraction of second
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
    });
    return nil;
}
```

c. In web/computer browser, the child window of web app is able to access source js functions using `window.opener` and `window.parent`

How to achieve the same functionality in `WKWebView`s? In other words, js functions in 2nd `WKWebView` could call js functions from parent/source `WKWebView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely should not return `nil` from `webView:createWebViewWithConfiguration:forNavigationAction:windowFeatures:`, but an instance of your `WKWebView`.

Unfortunately, I have no way to verify this right now. But as far as I remember, the trick is also to not ignore `WKWebViewConfiguration` argument from `webView:createWebViewWithConfiguration:forNavigationAction:windowFeatures:` delegate method, but create a second `WKWebView` instance, passing this argument as one of the `initWithFrame:configuration:` parameters.

Also, according Apple documentation, looks like you don't need to load the request yourself if you're returning correct web view instance. WebKit should handle this for you.

Overall your code should look similar to:

```
- (nullable WKWebView *)webView:(WKWebView *)webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration forNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction windowFeatures:(WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures {
    WKWebView *childWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGFrameZero configuration:configuration];
    WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithWebView: childWebView];

    // looks like this is no longer required, but I can't check it now :(
    // [childWebView loadRequest:navigationAction.request];

    // Show controller without interfering the current flow of API call, thus dispatch after a fraction of second
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
    });
    return childWebView;
}
```

Comment: Good catch, this looks like a promising answer. Excited. Will give it a shot today.

Comment: Confirming that the combination of 
1. new WKWebView instance with the given configuration passed, and 
2. returning this new instance from the listed method 
makes passing javascript `window.opener` messages between these "child page" and "parent page" work, which is truly incredible. The load request also is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to accomplish your task will be to have one WKWebView, and use HTML to separate header and detail.  The simplest solution is to have one HTML document with the header and all of the details, but if you need to add details dynamically that can also be done use the DOM.  Reusing Javascript for both the header and detail will be easiest with this approach.

Comment: Actually, opening the data in 2 separate WKWebViews is a prerequisite so that we can reuse web app architecture for this feature in our app. Also, from user perspective, it would provide same experience in web app as well as native app.